Creating special Compass Tuplet in MuseScore 3
I'm not musician, but I'm trying to help my song with a song for his School.
I took this image

from from https://musescore.com/user/39593079/scores/17210254
As you can see in measure 13:

What is the name for under bar and the 3 number? Is is Triplet?
How to create the same in MuseScore 3 without using shorcut (using menu)?

It's called a triplet. The way to create it in MuseScore 3 is to enter a quarter rest, select it (i.e., click on it), then use the menu command Add ->  Tuplets -> Triplet. This will create a bracketed triplet comprising three eighth rests. You can then enter the appropriate notes or leave rests where needed.
1. Enter a quarter rest
A. Empty measure

B. Select the note entry (far left) quarter note (middle) and rest  (right) icons from the toolbar.

C. Click on the measure to enter the rest

Note: In this example, MuseScore (correctly) adds two rests. This has to do with rules of music notation, but can be changed as needed.
2. Click on the quarter rest to select it.

3. Select Add -> Tuplets -> Triplet from the menu.
A. Selecting the menu command ...

B. ... results in ...

4. Enter notes as needed.

5. Bracket adjustment
MuseScore should automatically place the bracket underneath the notes in the specific case shown in the question. However, if necessary, the placement of the bracket can be changed by using the Element Inspector.
A. Click on the bracket to select it.

B. Select View -> Inspector from the menubar.

C. Change the "Direction" property as needed.

